# Display a custom tag within the TinyMce WYSIWYG view

Tags: html, tinymce

I have a suite of custom tags in my application that abstract some of the common system tasks.

I am using TinyMCE as my HTML editor, and want to be able to render my custom tag as an image in the editor when in the WYSIWYG view. Similar to TinyMCE's built-in behaviour for SWF files.

Is there an easy way to do this in TinyMCE?

**UPDATE:**

It seems that custom tags barely work in TinyMCE at all. 
Some of the problem seems to be that face that my tags are namespaced:

```
<o:some_tag />
```

Which is causing all sorts of issues.

Is there a editor that supports this kind of functionality better?

Comment: I don't know TinyMCE so I can't answer your question, but it should be pretty simple (essentially, a number of replace operations.) If nothing comes up here, you could check out the SWF behaviour in Tiny MCE's source code and see whether it can be extended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a method that meets my needs and  turned out to be a little easier than constructing a plugin.

Full details here: [How-To: Custom tags with TinyMCE](http://topsecretproject.finitestatemachine.com/2010/02/how-to-custom-tags-with-tinymce/).

Comment: The website is gone, but it is available in the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20140920214748/http://topsecretproject.finitestatemachine.com/2010/02/how-to-custom-tags-with-tinymce/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no easy way. Tinymce supports "extended_valid_elements" property . However as you want to render this custom tag as an image, all you can do is to create a [custom plugin](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Create_plugin/3.x) for your task

Comment: Also you can use standard plugins such as advhr as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try same code like  media plugin (it is not build-in behaviour, it is a plugin). Or yoy can check page break plugin.